# Intergrate Asp.net web api with azure mobile service(offline-online syncing).xamarin.android

Tags: asp.net-web-api, xamarin.android, azure-mobile-services

how can you Intergrate Asp.net web api with azure mobile service so as to do offline-online syncing xamarin.android app?

any code or samples

Answer (score 0):

As I known, [Mobile Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-value-prop#mobile-app-features) in Azure App Service supports **Offline Sync** while Azure Mobile Services (with the URL like:  **service.azure-mobile.net**) do not support this built-in feature. If you use Azure Mobile Service, I assumed that you need to [Migrate your existing Azure Mobile Service to Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-migrating-from-mobile-services), in order to use offline sync feature.

For developing a Xamarin.Android App with offline sync, you could follow this official [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-android-get-started) for creating an Azure Mobile App backend and download the Xamarin.Android demo project, then follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-android-get-started-offline-data) to enable offline sync for your mobile app. Additionally, you could refer to adrian hall's book about [Data Access and Offline Sync](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/dataconcepts/) for a better understanding of offline sync.